# Python scikit-learn (using grid_search.GridSearchCV)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using grid search to fit machine learning model parameters.

I typed in the following code (modified from the sklearn documentation page: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html)

```
from sklearn import svm, grid_search, datasets, cross_validation

# getting data
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# grid of parameters
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'poly'), 'C':[1, 10]}

# predictive model (support vector machine)
svr = svm.SVC()

# cross validation procedure
mycv = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(iris.target, n_folds = 2)

# grid search engine
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, parameters, mycv)

# fitting engine
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

However, when I look at `clf.estimator`, I get the following:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

How did I end up with a 'rbf' kernel?  I didn't specify it as an option in my parameters.

What's going on?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using '0.15-git' version for sklearn.

**Addendum**: I noticed that `clf.best_estimator_` gives the right output. So what is `clf.estimator` doing?

Comment: I believe in your parameters dictionary the `kernel` key should have a list as its values.  i.e. `['linear', 'poly']` (square brackets).  `rbf` just showed up because it is the default.

Comment: Thanks. So clf.estimator doesn't really do anything?  It's more like a placeholder for default values?

Comment: `estimator` is an object of the `GridSearchCV` class.  If you create an instance of this class, i.e. `clf`, `.estimator` will return the object  and in this case, since your initial code was erroneous, it returned the default.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!  Although fixing the code to 'kernel':['linear', 'poly'] still returns kernel='rbf' for the clf.estimator attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clf.estimator` is simply a copy of the estimator passed as the first argument to the `GridSearchCV` object. Any parameters not grid searched over are determined by this estimator. Since you did not explicitly set any parameters for the SVC object `svr`, it was given all default values. Therefore, because `clf.estimator` is just a copy of `svr`, printing the value of `clf.estimator` returns an SVC object with default parameters. Had you instead written, e.g.,

```
svr = svm.SVC(C=4.3)
```

then the value of `clf.estimator` would have been:

```
SVC(C=4.3, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

There is no real value to the user in accessing `clf.estimator`, but then again it wasn't meant to be a public attribute anyways (since it doesn't end with a "_").

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly meant to be a public attribute since it doesn't *start* with `_`. Attributes whose names *end* in `_` are *estimated* by `fit`. So both `estimator` and `best_estimator_` are public. The latter is the "result" of the grid search.